# Autocomplete text view in landscape mode - keyboard over dropdown

Tags: android, search, layout, autocompletetextview

In the landscape mode, the dropdown list for the AutoCompleteTextView is obstructed by the soft keyboard. How can this be fixed? Do I need to implement a custom solution?

Answer (score 1):

*I hope this will help you*

```
artistsSearchText.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            InputMethodManager in = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            in.hideSoftInputFromWindow(arg1.getWindowToken(), 0);

        }

    });

    artistsSearchText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
                return true;    
            }
            return false;
        }           
    });
```